# Delete an object created when another checkbox is selected in the same row in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, object, checkbox

I have a simple table with descriptions and two columns representing a state: YES and NO.

[image: table]

Each checkbox represents an object in which it includes the "Condition" property that is null at startup. Depending on what is marked, an array of objects is formed. What I want to do is that when another checkbox in the same row is selected, delete the previously created object. Without affecting the other rows.

For example when I select a checkbox:

[image: check1]

And by selecting the other checkbox, I would like to delete the previous object

[image: check2]

I was playing around with the event checked and change to prevent the user from selecting the two checkboxes in the same row. Also to delete the created object by unchecking a selected checkbox, making the "Condition" true or false.

I have a demo on stackblitz: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bk9zpg)

.HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="demoFormGroup" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:30px">
  <div formArrayName="info">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>YES</th>
        <th>NO</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let x of data; let i = index">
        <td>{{x.Description}}</td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox
            (change)="onChange($event,x,true)"
            [checked]="x.Condition"
          ></mat-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-checkbox
            (change)="onChange($event,x,false)"
            [checked]="x.Condition != null && !x.Condition"
          ></mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
<pre>{{ demoFormGroup.get('info')?.value | json }}</pre>
```

.TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  demoFormGroup: FormGroup;
  data: any;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.demoFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      info: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.data = [
      {
        Id: 4,
        Description: 'Option 1',
        Condition: null
      },
      {
        Id: 6,
        Description: 'Option 2',
        Condition: null
      }
    ];
  }

  onChange(event: any, option: any, enabled: boolean) {
    option.Condition = enabled;
    const ctrl = (<FormArray>this.demoFormGroup.get('info')) as FormArray;
    if (event.checked) {
      ctrl.push(new FormControl(option));
    } else {
      this.removeObject(ctrl, event);
    }
  }
  removeObject(ctrl: any, event: any) {
    const i = ctrl.controls.findIndex(
      (x: any) => x.value === event.source.value
    );
    ctrl.removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: youre objects are being duplicated right ?

Comment: @FaizalHussain The only thing that changes is the property "Condition" according to the checkbox selected in true or false

Comment: why are you using checkboxes? if you want to have just one value selected you can use radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several options to achieve that the simplest approach could be get all the selected `Ids` and check that if the newly selected option Id is already exist then do not push to array.

i.e:

```
    if (event.checked) {
       // Get the form value
       const selectedOptions = ctrl.value;
      // Create a new array with only selected Ids
       const selectedIds = selectedOptions.map(option => option.Id);

      // Here before pushing to control array check if value does not exist.
      if (!selectedIds.includes(option.Id)) {
        ctrl.push(new FormControl(option));
       }
    } else {
      this.removeObject(ctrl, event);
    }
```